# gradle-bintray-plugin Plugin [id: 'com.jfrog.bintray', version: '1.+'] was not found

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin, bintray

I'm trying to use the gradle plugin `gradle-bintray-plugin`.

Currently using Gradle 4.4

Following [the tutorial in the github page](https://github.com/bintray/gradle-bintray-plugin#getting-started-using-the-plugin) I should add the plugin in this way:

```
plugins {
    ...
    id "com.jfrog.bintray" version "1.+"
}
```

I'm receiving this error message and not being able to continue:

> Plugin [id: 'com.jfrog.bintray', version: '1.+'] was not found in any
>   of the following sources:
>
> - Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
> - Plugin Repositories (dynamic plugin versions are not supported) Open File

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dynamic versions were maybe authorized in the past for the `plugins` block (as the tutorial gives it as an example) but now [it's forbidden](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/plugin-use/src/main/java/org/gradle/plugin/use/resolve/internal/ArtifactRepositoriesPluginResolver.java#L72)

```
if (versionSelectorScheme.parseSelector(markerVersion).isDynamic()) {
    result.notFound(SOURCE_NAME, "dynamic plugin versions are not supported");
    return;
}
```

But it's not the case for the old `buildscript` way and the below code is working fine with Gradle 4.10

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.+'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 4):

I just find out the solution. Looks like it just works specifying the exact version that you want to use.

So changing this:

```
plugins {
    ...
    id "com.jfrog.bintray" version "1.+"
}
```

To this:

```
plugins {
    ...
    id "com.jfrog.bintray" version "1.8.4" // exact version!
}
```

**Now Works!**